# Perfect way to write a gsub for a regex match?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write  a gsub for a regex match, but I imagine there's a more perfect way to do this .

My equation :

```
ref.gsub(ref.match(/settings(.*)/)[1], '')
```

So that I can take this `settings/animals`, and return just `settings`.

But what if `settings` is null? Than my `[1]` fails as expected.

So how can one write the above statement assuming that sometimes `settings` won't match ?

So that basically, if it finds the word, `settings`, than get rid of anything after it. But if it doesn't, no worries.

Thanks!

Comment: This one is also a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190422/the-perfect-way-to-gsub-a-regex-match

Comment: Lev, that other one was caused by an error with Stackoverflow.com . It didn't post, then I guess it discreetly posted with a 500 error. I deleted the other one.

Comment: Sorry, I kinda lost my way in the three copies of the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not do the simplest possible thing that could work?

```
ref.gsub(/(settings)(.*)/, '\1')
```