# How can one write this gsub regex match?

Tags: ruby, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Perfect way to write a gsub for a regex match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190449/perfect-way-to-write-a-gsub-for-a-regex-match)

I am trying to write a gsub for a regex match, but I imagine there's a more perfect way to do this .

My equation :

```
ref.gsub(ref.match(/settings(.*)/)[1], '')
```

So that I can take this `settings/animals`, and return just `settings`.

But what if `settings` is null? Than my `[1]` fails as expected.

So how can one write the above statement assuming that sometimes `settings` won't match ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `/(settings|)(.*)/`, then first group will return you *"settings"* or empty string, if it is not present.

```
puts 'settings/123'.match(/(settings|)(.*)/)[1];
puts 'Xettings/123'.match(/(settings|)(.*)/)[1];
```

Comment: This seems to be what you want now. :)